# How can I have a dynamically allocated DOM event fire as well as a backbone event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

I want to have a loader attached on my buttons on mousedown on every page.

I have a function that fires after the layout renders and passes in the top level view, then grabs every button and attaches a mousedown event on it :

```
attachGlobalButtonEventHandler : function(view){
        view.$el.find('button.viewtag, button.newtag').on('mousedown', function(){
            var $target = $(this);

            $target.addClass('activated');
            $target.prop('disabled', true);
        });
    }
```

This works fine, but the problem is my backbone events on the buttons are not getting fired, which looks like:

```
events : {
            'click .newtag' : 'gotoCreate'
        },
        gotoCreate : function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();

            app.router.navigate('somewhere', true);
        }
```

If I remove the `attachGlobalButtonEventHandler`, then the click on `newtag` fires fine, but does not fire at all if the handler is attached. How can I make sure the backbone click event will fire as well?

Comment: Can you fire your event from the backbone event handler?

Comment: I could, but I don't want to go around to my site and add this everywhere i click on a button. the idea is to take care of it all at once

Comment: There might be some concurrency problems between the `click` and `mousedown` events, the `mousedown` being triggered before the click.

Comment: @ricard.m.o. i don't think this is the issue. if I change it to mouseup or click it still doesn't work.

Comment: I reckon the problem is that you're disabling the button. That prevents the click event from firing. Try wrapping the code to disable the button in a setTimeout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is the `disabled` property and the order events are executed.

The `mousedown` event happens before the `click` event and in the `mousedown` callback you disable the button, thus removing the `click` event entirely.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4DBs/) out. If you comment out the line `$(this).prop('disabled', true);` then the `click` event will fire.

By adding a `setTimeout` you can effectively execute it on the next tick, see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vtb3Z/) for details.

**Edit:** I just noticed @codemonkey had added a comment suggesting the same thing.